# Why can I not move the .panel pricing section to the centre of the webpage?

Tags: html, css

There are several things I cannot figure out:

1. The class .panel. Any CSS I apply to this class should apply to the whole panel, but it does not. (line 153, 235), most of it does but I cannot get it to centre screen.
2. On line 235 the CSS is only applied if I use .panel if I change the class name in HTML of this section and then change the class name in CSS, the CSS no longer works.
3. My main aim right now is to make the site responsive and get that panel centered, currently I have to scroll sideways to see the whole page, admittedly on the sizing issue I have not done much research but perhaps someone can give me a quick tip on it.

```css
/* * {
  
} */

#title1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-decoration: #D8E2DC;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
}

#title2 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-decoration: #000000;
    font-size: 80px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 440px;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}

body {
    background-color: #FB8500;
}

#type {
    border: 1px solid #D8E2DC;
    background-color: #FFB703;
    border-style: solid;
}

#price {
    border: 1px solid #D8E2DC;
    background-color: #F8EDEB;
    border-style: solid;
}

#time {
    border: 1px solid #D8E2DC;
    background-color: #F8EDEB;
    border-style: solid;
}

.navigation {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    bottom: 135px;
}

#home {
    background: none;
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
}

#home:hover {
    border-color: #a7b13f;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #023047;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#about {
    background: none;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
}

#about:hover {
    border-color: #a7b13f;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #023047;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#contact {
    background: none;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
}

#contact:hover {
    border-color: #f1ff5c;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #023047;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#signup {
    background: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
}

#signup:hover {
    border-color: #f1ff5c;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #023047;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#logo {
    max-height: 70px;
    max-width: 70px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 320px;
    left: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#logo:hover {
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
}

.table {
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px;
}




.panel {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Exams {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
}

.Exams:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.logo-img {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.pricing-header {
    color: #888;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.pricing-features {
    margin: 50px 0 25px;
    color: #016ff9;
}

.pricing-features-item {
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 15px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e1f1ff;
}

.pricing-features-item:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1f1ff;
}

.pricing-price {
    color: #016ff9;
    display: block;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.pricing-button {
    border: 1px solid #9dd1ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #348efe;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 25px 0;
    transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.pricing-button:hover, .pricing-button:focus {
    background-color: #e1f1ff;
}

.pricing-button.is-featured {
    background-color: #48aaff;
    color: white;
}

.pricing-button.is-featured:hover, .pricing-button.is-featured:focus {
    background-color: #269aff;
    color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .panel{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .Exams {
        border-bottom: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #e1f1ff;
        padding: 25px 50px;
    }
    .Exams:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader:wght@200&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=Dancing+Script&family=Josefin+Slab:wght@100&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Portfolio</title>

</head>

<nav id="title1">
    <h1>Learn online with
        <span id=title2>David</span>
    </h1>
</nav>

<nav class="navigation">

    <button id="about" class="navigation"><a href="#about">About</a></button>

    <button id="contact" class="navigation"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></button>

    <button id="signup" class="navigation"><a href="#signup">Sign up</a></button>

    <button id="home" class="navigation"><a href="#home">Home</a></button>
</nav>

<body>

    <main>

        <img id="logo" src="LOWD.png">

        <section class="panel">
            <div class="Exams">
                <img src="LOWD.png" alt="" class="logo-img">
                <h2 class="pricing-header">Enterprise</h2>
                <ul class="pricing-features">
                    <li class="pricing-features-item">Dedicated</li>
                    <li class="pricing-features-item">Simple horizontal scalability</li>
                </ul>
                <span class="pricing-price">$400</span>
                <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Free trial</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Exams">
                <img src="LOWD.png" alt="" class="logo-img">
                <h2 class="pricing-header">Something else</h2>
                <ul class="pricing-features">
                    <li class="pricing-features-item">Dedicated</li>
                    <li class="pricing-features-item">Simple horizontal scalability</li>
                </ul>
                <span class="pricing-price">$400</span>
                <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Free trial</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Exams">
                <img src="LOWD.png" alt="" class="logo-img">
                <h2 class="pricing-header">Another thing</h2>
                <ul class="pricing-features">
                    <li class="pricing-features-item">Dedicated</li>
                    <li class="pricing-features-item">Simple horizontal scalability</li>
                </ul>
                <span class="pricing-price">$400</span>
                <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Free trial</a>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                <th id="type">Exam type</th>
                <th id="time">30 minutes</th>
                <th id="time">45 minutes</th>
                <th id="time">1 hour</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="type">IELTS</td>
                <td id="price">$15</td>
                <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="type">FCE</td>
                <td id="price">$15</td>
                <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">CAE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">CAE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">CPE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">BEC</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">OGE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">EGE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">GRE</td>
                    <td id="price">$20</td>
                    <td id="price">$27.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$35</td>
                </tr>

            </table>-->
            </div>

        </section>

        <section id=flexpractice>
            <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
            <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
            <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
            <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
            <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
        </section>


    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should add **margin: auto;** on **.panel** to center the section. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. add:`margin:auto;`on class panel will be work;
2. Dont't use: `position: relative;` on nav Tags,Try Other Way to do;
3. remove padding on className panel;